# How to make a QLineEdit not editable in Windows

Tags: c++, qt, readonly, qlineedit

I'm using Qt 5.2 and I would like to make a `QLineEdit` not editable. The problem with this is, that it doesn't appear like it. When using `setReadOnly(true)` it stays with white background and looks like it is still editable.

If I disable it, then it turns gray and the text also gets a lighter gray. The problem is, that one can not copy the text from it, in a disabled state.

So how can I make a `QLineEdit` properly non-editable and also make it look like it. In Windows such a control is usually gray, but the text stays black. Of course I could set the style manually, but this means that it is hard-coded and may look wrong on other platforms.

Comment: Gray is for "disabled" widgets, not for read-only ones. They are different ideas.

Comment: .setEnabled(false)
This will make it gray and not editable.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

After making the line edit readonly, you can set the background and text colors to whatever you like :

```
ui->lineEdit->setReadOnly(true);

QPalette *palette = new QPalette();
palette->setColor(QPalette::Base,Qt::gray);
palette->setColor(QPalette::Text,Qt::darkGray);
ui->lineEdit->setPalette(*palette);
```

Comment: It's not exactly what I wanted, but it led me into the right direction. :) Thx.

Answer (score 5):

Since Nejat pointed me into the right direction with his answer, here is the code, that I now use:

```
QPalette mEditable = mGUI->mPathText->palette();  // Default colors
QPalette  mNonEditable = mGUI->mPathText->palette();
QColor col = mNonEditable.color(QPalette::Button);
mNonEditable.setColor(QPalette::Base, col);
mNonEditable.setColor(QPalette::Text, Qt::black);

....

void MyWidget::setEditable(bool bEditable)
{
    mGUI->mPathText->setReadOnly(!bEditable);
    if(bEditable)
        mGUI->mPathText->setPalette(mEditable);
    else
        mGUI->mPathText->setPalette(mNonEditable);
}
```

Comment: Probably because you gave credit where it's due and someone didn't read your answer all the way through... Nice answer BTW.

Comment: My only suggestion would be to change `QPalette::Button` to `QPalette::Window` and `Qt::black` to `QPalette::WindowText` for portability.

Answer (score 4):

You could set a style sheet that changes the color of a `QLineEdit` object, if its `readOnly` property is set to true.

```
setStyleSheet("QLineEdit[readOnly=\"true\"] {"
              "color: #808080;"
              "background-color: #F0F0F0;"
              "border: 1px solid #B0B0B0;"
              "border-radius: 2px;}");
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and made a subclass `QLineView` derived from `QLineEdit`. Then, i reimplemented `void setReadOnly(bool)` and added a member var `QPalette activePalette_`

Store the `QLineEdit`s palette within the ctor.

My reimplemented method lokks like this

```
void QLineView::setReadOnly( bool state ) {
    QLineEdit::setReadOnly(state);
    if (state) {
        QPalette pal = this->activePalette_;
        QColor color = pal.color(QPalette::disabled, this->backgroundRole());
        pal.setColor(QPalette::Active, this->backgroundRole(), color);
        pal.setColor(QPalette::InActive, this->backgroundRole(), color);
        this->setPalette(pal);
    }
    else {
        this->setPalette(this->activePalette_);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why downvoted? I did not downvote it, but my hunch is it is not needed, as you could do the above solutions, or just use qlabel (with changed properties) without making a new subclass.

Comment: But can a label also display complex text like HTML with formatting?