# Is there a Qt widget that looks like a label to display text but can also be edited if double-clicked?

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qlabel, qlineedit

I want a widget in Qt that will act like a spreadsheet cell does. It can display text, then when the user double-clicks on it, it becomes editable. Once the user is done with editing and presses Enter, the text gets saved and the control is not editable anymore. If the user hits Escape while editing, then the control returns to its previous value.

One possible solution is sub-classing `QWidget`, `QLabel` and `QLineEdit`. Are there any other solutions available in Qt?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a QLineEdit not editable in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23915700/how-to-make-a-qlineedit-not-editable-in-windows)

Comment: @Mikhail, this will still require sub-classing and playing with style sheets, which does not make the code look that pretty. I was wondering if I can resort to a solution with delegates.

Comment: If the task is not done by Qt you will have to subclass, listen to events, etc. subclassifying is the most common task, what's wrong with that ?, create a nice .h file and there place your code. I do not know what a beautiful and beautiful answer just for you. :)

Comment: @eyllanesc, I like how the Qt example http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-spreadsheet-example.html is done for instance. It's using `QTableView`, which is too much for what I need. I was wondering if there is a similar solution for QLineEdit.

Comment: @armanali That is done by a delegate, and the delegate creates the editor according to the user's wishes, but the delegate only works in the classes that belong to QAbstractItemView such as QTableView, QListView, QTableWidget, QListWidget. Do you have any of those classes?

Comment: @eyllanesc, I don't. I have started the implementation with sub-classing. I will post the solution here, since I think it's a useful widget to have, at least in my opinion.

Comment: @armanali That is done by a delegate, and the delegate creates the editor according to the user's wishes, but the delegate only works in the classes that belong to QAbstractItemView such as QTableView, QListView, QTableWidget, QListWidget. Do you have any of those classes?

Comment: @armanali 
If the solution is the same as it is in the answers that are in the other question, better not, if it is different, better do it in the other question, since I see that your question is a duplicate.

Comment: @eyllanesc, it's not. What the answers are suggesting is playing with the style sheets and making a QLineEdit look like a label, and vice versa. I want to create a widget call it EditableLabel which can provide all of the functionality out of the box.

Comment: @eyllanesc, also my solution is something that switches the views back and forth. The answers are just showing how to make it read-only.

Comment: @armanali see https://stackoverflow.com/a/23918591/6622587

Comment: @eyllanesc, yes I have seen it. It's playing with color palettes to make it look like something that it's not. I don't like that solution.

Comment: @armanali What I indicate is that you must publish your answer in the other question since it is a solution for that question since your question is the same.

Comment: @eyllanesc, I think it's better if I edit my question first, then I post the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following version also implements the same functionalities of your answer but instead of subclassing the `QLineEdit` and the `QLabel` only use `eventFilter()` and instead of managing the visibility manually let `QStackedWidget` do it.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QFormLayout>
#include <QKeyEvent>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QStackedWidget>
#include <QVBoxLayout>

class MyEditableLabel: public QWidget{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString text READ text WRITE setText NOTIFY textChanged)
public:
    MyEditableLabel(QWidget *parent=nullptr):
        QWidget(parent),
        mLabel(new QLabel),
        mLineEdit(new QLineEdit)
    {
        setLayout(new QVBoxLayout);
        layout()->setMargin(0);
        layout()->setSpacing(0);
        layout()->addWidget(&stacked);

        stacked.addWidget(mLabel);
        stacked.addWidget(mLineEdit);
        mLabel->installEventFilter(this);
        mLineEdit->installEventFilter(this);
        setSizePolicy(mLineEdit->sizePolicy());
        connect(mLineEdit, &QLineEdit::textChanged, this, &MyEditableLabel::setText);
    }

    bool eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event){
        if (watched == mLineEdit) {
            if(event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress){
                QKeyEvent *keyEvent = static_cast<QKeyEvent *>(event);
                if(keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_Return ||
                        keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_Escape ||
                        keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_Enter)
                {
                    mLabel->setText(mLineEdit->text());
                    stacked.setCurrentIndex(0);
                }
            }
            else if (event->type() == QEvent::FocusOut) {
                mLabel->setText(mLineEdit->text());
                stacked.setCurrentIndex(0);
            }
        }
        else if (watched == mLabel) {
            if(event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonDblClick){
                stacked.setCurrentIndex(1);
                mLineEdit->setText(mLabel->text());
                mLineEdit->setFocus();
            }
        }
        return QWidget::eventFilter(watched, event);
    }
    QString text() const{
        return mText;
    }
    void setText(const QString &text){
        if(text == mText)
            return;
        mText == text;
        emit textChanged(mText);
    }
signals:
    void textChanged(const QString & text);
private:
    QLabel *mLabel;
    QLineEdit *mLineEdit;
    QStackedWidget stacked;
    QString mText;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QWidget w;
    QFormLayout *lay = new QFormLayout(&w);

    MyEditableLabel el;
    lay->addRow("MyEditableLabel: ", &el);
    lay->addRow("QLineEdit: ", new QLineEdit);
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: Doesn’t the usage of event filter affect the performance? I’ve heard it’s faster when you sub-class, rather than install an event filter to a widget.

Comment: No, where you saw that, the event filter serves to listen to events without subclassing. and Qt uses it intensely.

Comment: Well you have to register an event filter with the application. So doesn’t that add overhead on top of the existing event filter?

Comment: @armanali I just add an element to a list that has the widget, how much overhead will that be?

Comment: I don’t know. I have read it somewhere. Maybe the information was not accurate.

Comment: @armanali Well, as I say I have used many times to avoid inheriting a class just to hear an event because if subclassing for it would have to create more memory to exchange data, if necessary for example the model

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `QInputdialog` to change `QLabel` and override the `mouseDoubleClickEvent` to trigger the input dialog.

I, as some here have learned that there is no means to pull edited text from a `QLabel`. Not without changing `QLabel`s internal code.

Here's an example using a `QInputDialog`, as means:

```
//intrlbl.h

#ifndef INTRLBL_H
#define INTRLBL_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QMouseEvent>



class intrLbl: public QLabel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    intrLbl(QWidget *parent);

    void mouseDoubleClickEvent(QMouseEvent *event) override;
    QString text;

};

#endif // INTRLBL_H



//intrlbl.cpp file

#include "intrlbl.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QInputDialog>

intrLbl::intrLbl(QWidget *parent)
{
    this->setText("Text Changeable Via Double Click QInput Dialog");
    this->setFocusPolicy(Qt::ClickFocus);
    this->setWordWrap(false);

}

void intrLbl::mouseDoubleClickEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
       QString title
               = QInputDialog::getText(this,
                 tr("Enter your Idea Title:"),
                  tr("Title:"), QLineEdit::Normal,
                  tr("enter your title here"));

      if(!title.isEmpty())
      {
            qDebug() << "Title set to:" << title;
            this->setText(title);
       }
      else
      {
          title = "Title";
          this->setText(title);
      }
}
```

Comment: Another Idea I've not successfully completed is to inherit QLineEdit. QLine edit has methods to hide the frame adjust background color and set read only mode. This would entail overriding the double click event and using a key press event on enter which adds more code and would not be as performant. One issue I've encountered is that when I implement keypress event I can no longer edit the text in QLineEdit. Any info on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions is to have a QLineEdit and set it to read-only and style it in a way that it will look like a label. I personally do not like this solution, because it's more of a hacking approach. I have come up with something that in my opinion is pretty cool, which includes sub-classing `QWidget`, `QLabel` and `QLineEdit`:

Let's first introduce a model, which will be created in the sub-classed version of our `QWidget` and this model will be passed to its child widgets, the sub-classed versions of `QLabel` and `QLineEdit`:

Model header - `mymodel.h`:

```
#ifndef MYMODEL_H
#define MYMODEL_H

#include <QObject>

class MyModel : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(Mode mode READ getMode WRITE setMode NOTIFY modeChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString text READ getText WRITE setText NOTIFY textChanged)
public:
    enum class Mode {
        ReadOnly = 0,
        Edit = 1,
    };

    explicit MyModel(QObject* parent = nullptr);

    Mode getMode() const {
        return _mode;
    }

    const QString& getText() const {
        return _text;
    }

signals:
    void modeChanged(Mode mode);
    void textChanged(const QString& text);

public slots:
    void setMode(Mode mode);
    void setText(const QString& text);

private:
    Mode _mode;
    QString _text;
};

#endif // MYMODEL_H
```

Model implementation - `mymodel.cpp`

```
#include "mymodel.h"

MyModel::MyModel(QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent)
    , _mode(MyModel::Mode::ReadOnly)
    , _text(QString()) {
}

void MyModel::setMode(MyModel::Mode mode) {
    if (_mode != mode) {
        _mode = mode;
        emit modeChanged(_mode);
    }
}

void MyModel::setText(const QString &text) {
    if (_text != text) {
        _text = text;
        emit textChanged(text);
    }
}
```

As we see the model has the text, which is common for both the `QLabel` and the `QLineEdit`, and it has a mode, which can be either read only or edit mode.

The label implementation is a sub-class of `Label`.
Header - `mylabel.h`:

```
#ifndef MYLABEL_H
#define MYLABEL_H

#include <QLabel>
#include <QSharedPointer>

#include "mymodel.h"

class MyLabel : public QLabel {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyLabel(QWidget *parent = 0);
    void setModel(QSharedPointer<MyModel> model);

protected:
    void mouseDoubleClickEvent(QMouseEvent *) override;

private:
    QSharedPointer<MyModel> _model;
};

#endif // MYLABEL_H
```

Implementation - `mylabel.cpp`:

```
#include "mylabel.h"

#include <QMouseEvent>

MyLabel::MyLabel(QWidget *parent)
    : QLabel(parent) {
}

void MyLabel::setModel(QSharedPointer<MyModel> model) {
    _model = model;
}

void MyLabel::mouseDoubleClickEvent(QMouseEvent *) {
    _model->setText(text());
    _model->setMode(MyModel::Mode::Edit);
}
```

As we our class MyLabel has a setModel() method, which will take the model from its parent. We are overriding the `mouseDoubleClickEvent()`, though which we are setting the text of the model to whatever text there is in the label, and setting the mode to edit, because when double-clicking we want to edit the text.

Now let's take a look at the `QLineEdit`. Our version of `QLineEdit`, called `MyLineEdit`, is listening to keyboard events and when Enter and Esc keys are pressed it either saves the text to the model, or discards it. Then it changes the mode to read-only.

`MyLineEdit.h`:

```
#ifndef MYLINEEDIT_H
#define MYLINEEDIT_H

#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QSharedPointer>

#include "mymodel.h"

class MyLineEdit : public QLineEdit {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyLineEdit(QWidget* parent = nullptr);
    void setModel(QSharedPointer<MyModel> model);

protected:
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* event) override;
    void focusOutEvent(QFocusEvent*);

private:
    QSharedPointer<MyModel> _model;
};

#endif // MYLINEEDIT_H
```

And here's the implementation - `MyLineEdit.cpp`:

```
#include "mylineedit.h"

#include <QKeyEvent>

MyLineEdit::MyLineEdit(QWidget *parent)
    : QLineEdit(parent) {
}

void MyLineEdit::setModel(QSharedPointer<MyModel> model) {
    _model = model;
}

void MyLineEdit::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event) {
    if (event->key() == Qt::Key_Enter) {
        _model->setText(text());
        _model->setMode(MyModel::Mode::ReadOnly);
    } else if (event->key() == Qt::Key_Escape) {
        _model->setMode(MyModel::Mode::ReadOnly);
    } else {
        QLineEdit::keyPressEvent(event);
    }
}

void MyLineEdit::focusOutEvent(QFocusEvent *) {
    _model->setText(text());
    _model->setMode(MyModel::Mode::ReadOnly);
}
```

So now we have the model, we have our version of `QLabel` and our version of `QLineEdit`. What we want now is a parent widget that will contain both of them, listen to signals from the model and change its appearance based on the signals. That class is derived from `QWidget` and is called `MyEditableLabel`:

`MyEditableLabel.h`:

```
#ifndef MYEDITABLELABEL_H
#define MYEDITABLELABEL_H

#include <QSharedPointer>
#include <QWidget>

#include "mylabel.h"
#include "mylineedit.h"

class MyEditableLabel : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyEditableLabel(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    QString getText() const {return _text;}
private:
    MyLabel *_label;
    MyLineEdit *_lineEdit;
    QSharedPointer<MyModel> _model;

private slots:
    void onModeChanged(MyModel::Mode mode);
    void onTextChanged(const QString &text);

private:
    QString _text;
};

#endif // MYEDITABLELABEL_H
```

`MyEditableLabel.cpp`:
    #include "myeditablelabel.h"

```
#include <QHBoxLayout>

MyEditableLabel::MyEditableLabel(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent) {
    _model = QSharedPointer<MyModel>(new MyModel());
    _model->setText("Click me!");
    _label = new MyLabel(this);
    _label->setModel(_model);
    _lineEdit = new MyLineEdit(this);
    _lineEdit->setModel(_model);
    _lineEdit->setReadOnly(false);

    QHBoxLayout *mainLayout = new QHBoxLayout();
    mainLayout->setMargin(0);
    mainLayout->setSpacing(0);
    mainLayout->addWidget(_label);
    mainLayout->addWidget(_lineEdit);
    setLayout(mainLayout);

    connect(_model.data(), &MyModel::modeChanged, this, &MyEditableLabel::onModeChanged);
    onModeChanged(_model->getMode());
    connect(_model.data(), &MyModel::textChanged, this, &MyEditableLabel::onTextChanged);
    onTextChanged(_model->getText());
}

void MyEditableLabel::onModeChanged(MyModel::Mode mode) {
    _lineEdit->setVisible(mode == MyModel::Mode::Edit);
    _lineEdit->selectAll();
    _label->setVisible(mode == MyModel::Mode::ReadOnly);
}

void MyEditableLabel::onTextChanged(const QString &text) {
    _lineEdit->setText(text);
    _label->setText(text);
    _text = text;
}
```

`Usage:`
Using this is pretty straightforward. If you're using the `Qt Creator` designer, then you want to draw a `QWidget` and the right click on it and promote it to `MyEditableLabel` and you're done. If you're not using the `Qt Creator` designer then you just have to create and instance of `MyEditableLabel` and you're in business.

`Improvements:`
It probably is a better idea to not create the model in the constructor of `MyEditableLabel`, but outside of it and have a `setModel` method in `MyEditableLabel`.

Comment: Much logic for such a simple task, I would use a QStackedLayout, I do not see the need for the model.

Comment: @eyllanesc, then post your solution:)

Comment: to detect the events of the QLabel click or the QLineEdit would use an event filter.

Comment: I'll do it, why do you use a model?

Comment: @eyllanesc, it does the job. And it’s clean:)

Comment: @eyllanesc, to sync between the QLabel and the QLineEdit.

Comment: @eyllanesc, it’s good not to have the QLabel be aware of the QLineEdit and the other way around. It gives more flexibility.

Comment: I have published following his same logic but with alternative methods, try it.